# Unable to use emulator on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I am trying to run an app using the emulators on the Android Studio, it is stuck on this window.

[image]

It should let the user to select an emulator.

[image]

What could be the cause for that errors?

Comment: Do you only have one emulator configured?

Comment: Seems message clearly says that you have set RAM less than minimum values.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes I have seen this when adb isn't able to start. That doesn't seem to be your problem. I can suggest going to your android sdk folder run the avd manager program and see if you can repair / adjust any settings you may need.